# Laravel logout create a session timeout

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel and everything is going well.

The only thing, afther I try to terminate the user session (logout) and immediately authenticate myself again, it throws a 419 - Session Expired.

I think that I use the logout correctly.

```
<li><a onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();" href="/logout">Uitloggen</a>
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">@csrf</form>
```

Did I do something wrong? And the most important, how to solve it?

Expected result: 
1. User logs in
2. User hit Logoff 
3. User can login again

Actual result:
1. User logs in
2. User hit Logoff 
3. User need to remove the cookies before he can login again

Comment: remove the `href` from the Uitloggen anchor, and try.

Comment: @TharakaDilshan I still can't login. When I enter my credentials and enter submit, it results in a 419 :( (after your suggested change ofcourse ;) )

Comment: I think the problem is not with this code. Becase i have the exact same, THE EXACT SAME code in my project. A glance of your routes may be help others to find the issue

Comment: I'm just using the never-editted `Auth::routes();
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found!

My storage directory had the wrong access rights
Changed it to 777 (not a production server)

Solved!